# How create a swift module with unistd.h

Tags: swift

I read [an article](https://dzone.com/articles/using-a-c-library-in-swift) about importing c libs into a swift module. What if you don't need a library and just multiple system headers like unistd.h, fcntl.h, sys/socket.h or netinet/in.h? What are you supposed to put in the module.modulemap file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in the module.modulemap worked for me

```
module SwiftCWrapper [system] {
   header "unistd.h"
   export *
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most system headers are already in a module for Swift. `import Darwin` (or `import Glibc` if using open source Swift on Linux) and you'll get the lot of them.

If you want to browse the module interface in Xcode to see what the Swift declarations of those APIs look like, one good way is to type one in your source file (say, `arc4random`) and cmd-click it. You can then browse through the rest of the module.

Comment: Thanks. The seems more of a comment than an answer. The functions I need are not in Darwin->c->stdlib. There is a patch pending for one though.